# Why do compilers now accept to call str() member on a returned std::ostream& from std::stringstream::operator<<()?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following line:

```
std::string s = (std::stringstream() << "foo").str();
```

This should not compile because `std::stringstream::operator<<()` is inherited by `std::ostream` and returns a `std::ostream&` which **does not have** an `str()` member.

It seems the main compilers are now accepting this code where they didn't in the past. What standard change happened to make this compile?

I made some tests with *[GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)*, *[Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang)* and *[MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B)* and I could find the version where the change happened:

| Compiler | Rejects until (version) | Accepts from (version) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GCC | 11.1 | 11.2 |
| Clang | 12.0.1 | 13.0.0 |
| MSVC | v19.14 | v19.15 |

<sup>You can [find the test here](https://godbolt.org/z/hn7jGo5c1)</sup>

Comment: Very strange bug indeed.

Comment: Note that `auto t = (std::stringstream() << "foo"); std::cout << typeid(t).name() << "\n";` shows the type of `t` to be *class std::basic_stringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >*, so the 'bug' (if that's what it is) is there, not in the use of the `.str()` member.

Comment: fwiw here you can see that the type of `(std::stringstream() << "foo")` changed: https://godbolt.org/z/hE38cKTdj

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They all added the rvalue overload (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)) at around the same time.

The rvalue overload was <strike>introduced in</strike> added to C++11 and returns the same type of stream as its left-hand operand.

As has been noted in the comments, the reason for it being added to the compilers seemingly after a whole decade is that it was added to C++11 *retroactively* and very recently, probably after being approved for inclusion in C++20.

I'm turning this into a community wiki in case anyone has the inclination and patience to search for the reasoning behind the retroactive addition and amend the answer.

Comment: The way I read the specifications it was _retroactively_ introduced in C++11 after 2018-05-25; meaning that they all were late with adding a feature that was added late.

Comment: @HansOlsson That sounds more than plausible. Do you mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: @hansolsson - when you say introduced in c++11, do you mean introduced in c++20 or literally added to the (superceded 3 times) c++11 spec in 2018?

Comment: @KarlNicoll: Hans emphasised 'retroactively' so I take it as "yes, moved back in time, and added to the old spec". Odd thing but happens sometimes for very important features. I'm not Hans though, so not 100% sure.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - yeah I guess you're right, and its listed as a c++11 feature in cppref. It just seems wild that such a feature would be backported so far back, but then takes so many additional years to gain wide compiler support. It doesn't seem worth the effort! Crazy stuff.

Comment: Yes, that's [LWG 1203](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203). It was changed in C++11 retroactively. Why it took so long to implement that in compilers - no idea.

Comment: I don't mind you adding it to the answer. And I agree that it is weird in several ways - such a long delay in handling the defect, and then doing it retroactively. So you really can't blame compilers until it was actually changed, and I wrote after 2018-05-25, I'm not sure if it was retroactively added in C++1 in 2018 or as late as 2020.

Comment: Obviously I meant C++11 not C++1 above.

Comment: To make it compatible with both compiler versions, is it legal to `static_cast<std::stringstream&&>(...)` the returned value ? [It compiles and (seems to) run successfully](https://godbolt.org/z/MzqWYjj4v) but I'm not sure if it's legal to downcast an `std::ostream` like that (I mean in the case the rvalue overload is not available. That cast is a no-op (and should be optimized out) otherwise).

Comment: @Fareanor The thing we used to do, before there were rvalue references, is `static_cast<std::stringstream&>`. This inconvenience is very old.

Comment: But this cast [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/czasGr8Ps) after the change. Hence why I suggested a cast to an rvalue reference instead.

Comment: But if it is not legal, the only solution left is to split into three lines, first instantiate a `std::stringstream`, perform the insertion and then call the `str()` member on the previously created instance.

Comment: @Fareanor I had no idea that it didn't work any more. The rvalue cast is the way, then. And it's legal.